# how to get parent widget width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

anyone know how can i get parent widget width ? i try to solve this problem on my UI below

[image]

here my widget tree

```
row
  expanded
     flex:8
      row
        column
          container(
            width : ???? // here i want to get width size of expanded flex: 8
            Wrap(
              children: [  
     Text('item A'),
     Text('item B'),
     Text('item C'),
     Text('item D'),
                      ],
     ),)
```

Comment: Hi There. You probably shouldn't be needing `LayoutBuilder` to solve your case. Post full code of your each `Item` widget.

Comment: solved by wrap column with expanded widget :)

Comment: Wonderful. Flutter is quite plain and simple

Comment: yeah , hahaha :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LayoutBuilder`, when you wrap the widget in it it will give you parent contraints